# IE error when redirecting to DHL tracking site: The value of the property dcsMultiTrack is null or undefined, not a Function Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, dhl

I ran into a browser-specific error when trying to redirect to DHL tracking site from my app

I have this key in the `AppSettings` in my `web.config` file

```
<add key ="DHL" value="http://www.dhl.com/en/express/tracking.html?AWB={tracking_number}"
```

I also have a `HyperLink` Control like this

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hlink" runat="server" Target="_blank">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Then I set the value in code behind:

```
hlink.NavigateUrl = String.Format(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DHL"], myClass.TrackingNumber)
```

When the I click on the url and gets redirect to the site, when the page loads, a Webpage error window popped up with following message:

> The value of the property dcsMultiTrack is null or undefined, not a
> Function Object

If I just ignore the message and hit "no" to the error window, the site will continue to load just fine.
However, it is really ugly that everytime I get redirect to DHL the error shows up.

This only happens to **IE**, I tested with **Edge** and it was fine. **Also,this function is not from my code, but from DHL's site.** So I am not sure if there is anything I can do about it. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I think this may have to do with the url am I using, is this URL out of date? what would be a good URL to redirect to DHL?

Comment: Does your app show this error? Or is it coming from the DHL site?

Comment: @mxmissile it is from DHL site, not from my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is the legacy DHL tracking site. For anyone who needs to use similar functionality, use the new URL instead:

```
https://www.dhl.com/us-en/home/tracking/tracking-express.html?submit=1&amp;tracking-id={0}
```